# Create an array of different types of Chai assertions and evaluate them later

Tags: javascript, chai

I have some kind of async (I/O bound) tasks to do then I want to `assert` the returned values with `Chai`. Instead of writing a piece of code like this

```js
expect(await taskA.someAsync()).to.be.eq(something);
expect(await taskB.someAsync()).to.be.eq(something);
```

I want to wait for all to complete with `await Promise.all([taskA.someAsync(), taskB.someAsync()])` and then `expect` or `assert` the results one by one.

I created this function(pseudocode) to make things more general:

```js
type TransactionInfo = {
    txn: Promise<any>; // Async task to be awaited
    assertion: Chai.Assertion // Assertion to be run on txn result
}

const assertAll = async function(...txns: TransactionInfo[]) {
  let values = await Promise.all(allTxns);
  for (let txnInfo of txns) {
    evaluate(txnInfo.assertion)
  }
}
```

What this function is supposed to do is to `await` for all `txns` and then run each `assertion` for each txn to verify the returned value.

First of all I'm not sure if the `Chai.Assertion` type is correct for `assertion`. Secondly, I don't know how to instantiate an array of `TransactionInfo` with different types of assertions like `eq` or `have.lengthOf`. And lastly, I don't know how to evaluate `assertion` objects later.

P.S. I'm not an expert javascript developer. Be kind please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { expect } from 'chai';

type TransactionInfo = {
  txn: Promise<any>; // Async task to be awaited
  assertion: () => void; // Function representing the assertion to be run on txn result
};

const assertAll = async function (...txns: TransactionInfo[]) {
  let values = await Promise.all(txns.map((txnInfo) => txnInfo.txn));
  txns.forEach((txnInfo, index) => {
    txnInfo.assertion(values[index]);
  });
};
```

With this code, you can now create an array of TransactionInfo objects, each with its own custom assertion function:

```
// Example usage:
const txn1: TransactionInfo = {
  txn: someAsyncTaskA(),
  assertion: (result) => {
    expect(result).to.be.eq(something);
  },
};

const txn2: TransactionInfo = {
  txn: someAsyncTaskB(),
  assertion: (result) => {
    expect(result).to.have.lengthOf(3);
  },
};

// Call the assertAll function with the array of TransactionInfo objects
await assertAll(txn1, txn2);
```